# Can I send an email without sharing?

Tags: email, email-template, sharing

I'm trying to send some emails using the `Messaging` API. I'm constructing instances of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`, setting the values of `whatId`, `whoId`, and `templateId`, and then sending through `Messaging.sendEmail`.

The problem is, the intended recipient (`whoId`) is a User that the running user doesn't have access to.

Is there a way I can disable this protection and send that email with the ID of any User?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the requirement, you should write custom `sendEmailToUser()` method in the class which is marked as **without sharing**.

This `sendEmailToUser()` method will call `sendEmail()` for sending emails.

That way, all other logic of the existing class' method will not get impacted.

Comment: That wouldn't work. `sendEmail()` is a built-in method.

Comment: I am talking about custom method which will call Salesforce sendEmail() method